# Intellij IDEA on Mac pops up a window randomly to interrupt coding

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Problem: 
I'm using idea on mac, and every time I start idea, it will pop up a window and interrupt me randomly. The window fleets very very quickly and I don't know how to solve it.(ps. eclipse doesn't show this problem)

Image of the problem:
[Please ignore the Chinese character in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWO18.png)

Tried:
 I've uninstalled Idea totally and Re-installed it, but the problem still exists.

Versions of macos and Idea: 
Catalina beta 10.15.4; Idea 2019.3.4; jdk 13.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this window will pop up again and again, and fleet so quickly, like a fly surrounds you...